# Apache Camel Validate Filename pattern

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wondered what the best approach for validating a filename is when consuming a file. I know I can use a pattern for exclusion and I have seen I can define a customer GenericFileFilter.

But these filters return a true or false. I prefer to throw an exception.

So I wonder if it is better to use a bean or custom processor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you pick up the file, you can call a processor where you can extract the filename from the exchange, using `exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName").toString();`
You can perform any validations you want and throw exceptions there.

You can do the same task in a bean, you just need to pass the `CamelFileName` header as a parameter to the bean.

If you don't want to call a processor you can do the same in the camel route as well. you can do something like

```
.choice()
    .when()
       .simple("${header.CamelFileName} == 'your condition'")
       .throwException(MyCustomException.class)
  .end()//ends the choice
  .continue_with_your_route
```